# Invitation using security key

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I would like to implement an invitation system for an ASP.NET application. The system administration can add email addresses that are saved in the DB associated to a security key. This security key is sent to the e-mail in a link. When the user clicks the link it can register a new account and everything goes on.

I am a security newbie, so I would like to know if there are simple and secure (it will not be NASA archive, obviously) ways to implement a mechanism like that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

- Create a row in the database and put the ID of the row and the [HMAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx) of the ID in the invitation. For example `?Register.aspx?UserId=3&hmac=54oreijwgoro564i3j2o543`. Because the client can not reproduce the HMAC for another ID, he can not simply change the URL to register another user.
- Create a row with some random and unique string. Because the string is random, it is hard to guess. When the user requests `?Register.aspx?Code=grewgkrwgoerwgrew432`, search the database for the row with that code. In some projects we use a [guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) as a random token, but I don't know how secure/random that is.

Comment: You missed an important point: mark the code as already used after usage.

Comment: Using the HMAC is secure, provided that you use a long key which you keep secret. You generate the HMAC to create the invitation link, and check in the Register.aspx page whether the given HMAC matches the ID.